# っていうことになったんですけど - meaning?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, usage, kanji

I had just received a somewhat rushed 'transliteration' of a 1 minute video. To me, Shigeru Miyamoto speaks in a way which is extremely difficult to understand. I am adding the full transcript just for context.

---

## Pokemon20: Nintendo's Shigeru Miyamoto

> ポケモン、２０周年おめでとうございます。

Pokémon, congratulations on your 20th anniversary.

> すると同時に、最初のポケモンに関わってたプロデューサーとしては皆さん、ポケモン、ここまで可愛がってくれて、ありがとうございます。

At the same time, as one of the producers on the very first Pokémon games, I want to say thank you for all your kind support.

> こう20年になるんですけども、その6年前ぐらい前から石原さんと、ポケモン作ろうって色々テストをしていまして、これがついつい時間がかかったら実はMother2を作っていたんですね？(< I'm not too sure that this was supposed to be a question.)
> で、Mother2が終わってさ、本格的にポケモンを作り始めましょう、っていうことになったんですけど僕は、任天堂のGameBoyで通信ケーブルを使った新しいゲームを田尻さんたち一緒に作ろう、ということの立場としてメインでかかっていました。

Although this year marks the 20th anniversary, I was working with Ishihara-san from about six years before that, testing out what would become the first Pokémon games.
The reason it took so long was because we were also working on EarthBound.
Once that was finished, we were able to move full speed ahead with Pokémon.
My main contribution was working with Tajiri-san and his team on creating a new way to play using a Nintendo Game Link Cable to connect two Game Boy systems.

---

I am assuming
で、「対談しよう」っていうことになったんですけど。 。 = So, it was decided to have a conversation.

Maybe its supposed to be:

> で、Mother2が終わってさ、本格的にポケモンを作り始めましょう、っていうことになったんですけど。僕は、~

> それがこう気がついたらこんなにたくさんの色は出る、20年も経つ、本当に、信じられない状態です。

Time flew by, and now there are Pokémon games in so many colours! Twenty years. I almost can’t believe it.

How does それがこう気がついたら = Time flew by ?
それが = that is
こう気がついたら = after this was realized/noticed

Perhaps Shigeru strings his sentences together too fast. So someone typing his speech out wouldn't be too sure where one sentence ends and another begins.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video of the short speech and Shigeru Miyamoto definitely says

**作り始めましょう**、っていうことになったんですけど...

First off, it doesn't matter if there's a period or a comma. Like in English, the meaning stays the same ("I accept it. However..." / "I accept it, however").

Then - like you've already demonstrated with 対談 - ことになった means "it was decided".

So what Shigeru Miyamoto said was "'Let's start making Pokemon!' is what we agreed on".

Remember that っていう figuratively puts quotes around a sentence and treats it as a thing, that can then be further explained (kinda like *"the fact that '...' is the reason that..."* or *"the decision to '...' is what we agreed on"*).

Comment: In English, there is many situations where a comma or period changes the meaning completely.